# Unable to listen to mail server using mail-listener2 nodejs

Tags: node.js

I'm new to node and i'm making an email client using gmail api. I'm using mail-listener2 to get new mail notification. It shows imapConnected but i don't get any notification on new mail. Can anyone guide me or point me to right direction.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question would fit better into the Stackoverflow Q&A scheme if you either ask how to do that instead of telling it does not work without providing code or by showing waht you've created so far, so that one can say the error is in this is that line.

Comment: Actually I'm using the mail-listener2 example from github itself but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Vivek, you're not alone, I had experienced the same problem, see alternative here:

[mail-listener2 doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344911/mail-listener2-doesnt-work/25357267#25357267)

if you're new to node remember to declare your dependencies in package.json at the root of your project and run npm install

example package.json:

```
 {
  "name": "exampleAppName",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
     "mail-notifier": "0.2.3"
  }
 }
```