# mail-listener2 doesn't work

Tags: node.js

This is my code for the mail-listener file.

I call the startListening function in my main file, and I can read "Imap connected" in the console , but then, even if some email arrives, nothing happens.

Any Idea?

```
var MailListener = require("mail-listener2");

var mailListener = new MailListener({
  username: "myEmail@gmail.com",
  password: "myPassword",
  host: "imap.gmail.com",
  port: 993, // imap port
  tls: true,
  tlsOptions: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
  mailbox: "INBOX", // mailbox to monitor
  searchFilter: ["UNSEEN", "FLAGGED"], // the search filter being used after an IDLE notification has been retrieved
  markSeen: true, // all fetched email willbe marked as seen and not fetched next time
});

module.exports.startListening = function(){
    mailListener.start(); // start listening
}

// stop listening
//mailListener.stop();

mailListener.on("server:connected", function(){
  console.log("imapConnected");
});

mailListener.on("server:disconnected", function(){
  console.log("imapDisconnected");
});

mailListener.on("error", function(err){
  console.log(err);
});

mailListener.on("mail", function(mail, seqno, attributes){
  // do something with mail object including attachments
  console.log("emailParsed", mail);
  // mail processing code goes here
});

mailListener.on("attachment", function(attachment){
  console.log(attachment.path);
});
```

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue. The example doesn't work. I'm using [mail-notifier](https://github.com/jcreigno/nodejs-mail-notifier) instead:

```
var notifier = require('mail-notifier');

var imap = {
      user: "_example@example.com_",
      password: "password",
      host: "imap.gmail.com",
      port: 993,
      tls: true,
      tlsOptions: { rejectUnauthorized: false }
};

notifier(imap).on('mail',function(mail){
         console.log("GOT MAIL");
}).start();
```

Works like a charm

Comment: I have this problems: Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/accounts/answer/78754 (Failure)

Comment: Try allowing less secure apps to connect. https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Answer (score 10):

For the snippet of code to work, remove the:

```
searchFilter: "FLAGGED"
```

Currently, you are just searching for unseen, flagged emails, and likely the incoming email is not flagged as important.  I had the exact implementation above, without the FLAGGED search filter, and this works perfectly.

Comment: This answer solved my problem without the need to change library.
My assumption was that the filter array should search for ANY of those conditions, not all of them. this implementation seems silly.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm removing the "searchFilter" option resolves the issue of future emails not being picked up / read. What appears to be happening is on initialization having

`searchFilter: 'ALL'`

downloads all emails and my event listener fires, however, subsequent emails don't trigger any listeners / callback.

Removing the searchFilter option resolved the issue and any emails that come in get downloaded and marked as read.

Hope this helps others who are using some version of the mailListener5, etc. lib